# Sending a GET request within a Google Action intent

Tags: javascript, node.js, actions-on-google

I'm new to Actions on Google and Node.js, but this seems like it should be straightforward and I'm not sure why it's not working. I just want to send a GET request within the code that handles a specific intent. At the moment, I'm not even looking for a return value; I just want to fire off the request. I'm using the Blaze tier of Firebase, which is supposed to allow outgoing HTTPS requests. Indeed, I can get the Action to play an audio file from my server in SSML. But when I put in a GET request to a PHP page that increments a value in a database, it isn't being executed successfully.

My code is taken directly from Google's CodeLabs tutorials for Actions. Below is the only function I'm modifying. This code runs, but the GET request is never received.

```
// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'favorite color'.
// The intent collects a parameter named 'color'.
app.intent('favorite color', (conv, {color}) => {
    const luckyNumber = color.length;
    const audioSound = 'https://my.server.tld/path/to/sound.mp3';

    // These two lines don't seem to do what I'm expecting them to.
    var https = require("https");
    https.get('https://my.server.tld/path/to/file.php?value=1');

    conv.ask(`<speak>Your lucky number is ${luckyNumber}.` +
        `<audio src="${audioSound}"></audio>` +
        `Would you like to hear some fake colors?</speak>`);
});
```

There's nothing that jumps out at me as unusual in the Firebase logs (excerpted below). There doesn't seem to be any mention of the GET call I'm trying to make.

```
4:19:11.631 PM dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment Function execution took 569 ms, finished with status code: 200
4:19:11.543 PM dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment Response { "status": 200, "headers": { "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" }, "body": { "payload": { "google": { "expectUserResponse": true, "richResponse": { "items": [ { "simpleResponse": { "textToSpeech": "<speak>Three. Your lucky number is 4.<audio src=\"https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/cartoon/clang_and_wobble.ogg\"></audio>Would you like to hear some fake colors?</speak>" } } ] }, "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}" } }, "outputContexts": [ { "name": "projects/actions-rwag/agent/sessions/ABwppHEUBtwbVHv-ECaw2yqSzZwdKjejoN3HrlpD8e0anrJytaT9jX8_zRMrW1-lJtC-W1TUFWKXLqLh/contexts/_actions_on_google", "lifespanCount": 99, "parameters": { "data": "{}" } } ] } }
4:19:11.434 PM dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment Conversation { "responses": [], "expectUserResponse": true, "digested": false, "noInputs": [], "_responded": false, "request": "[Excluded]", "headers": "[Excluded]", "sandbox": true, "input": { "raw": "blue", "type": "KEYBOARD" }, "surface": { "capabilities": { "list": [ { "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER" }, { "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO" }, { "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT" }, { "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT" } ] } }, "available": { "surfaces": { "list": [ { "capabilities": { "list": [ { "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER" }, { "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT" }, { "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT" } ] } } ], "capabilities": { "surfaces": [ { "capabilities": { "list": [ { "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER" }, { "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT" }, { "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT" } ] } } ] } } }, "user": { "raw": { "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}", "lastSeen": "2018-09-26T23:19:06Z", "locale": "en-US", "userId": "ABwppHHp5yhn_VrB_SIGG93tCzMx9o0A_W9bIDlbCClkqcV85LrVbJ42vLQ7hWXfe3UOd7pASDIm6v_q" }, "storage": {}, "_id": "ABwppHHp5yhn_VrB_SIGG93tCzMx9o0A_W9bIDlbCClkqcV85LrVbJ42vLQ7hWXfe3UOd7pASDIm6v_q", "locale": "en-US", "permissions": [], "last": { "seen": "2018-09-26T23:19:06.000Z" }, "name": {}, "entitlements": [], "access": {}, "profile": {} }, "arguments": { "parsed": { "input": { "text": "blue" }, "list": [ "blue" ] }, "status": { "input": {}, "list": [ null ] }, "raw": { "list": [ { "rawText": "blue", "textValue": "blue", "name": "text" } ], "input": { "text": { "rawText": "blue", "textValue": "blue", "name": "text" } } } }, "device": {}, "id": "ABwppHEUBtwbVHv-ECaw2yqSzZwdKjejoN3HrlpD8e0anrJytaT9jX8_zRMrW1-lJtC-W1TUFWKXLqLh", "type": "ACTIVE", "screen": true, "body": "[Excluded]", "version": 2, "action": "", "intent": "favorite color", "parameters": { "color": "blue" }, "contexts": { "_session": "projects/actions-rwag/agent/sessions/ABwppHEUBtwbVHv-ECaw2yqSzZwdKjejoN3HrlpD8e0anrJytaT9jX8_zRMrW1-lJtC-W1TUFWKXLqLh", "input": { "actions_capability_screen_output": { "name": "projects/actions-rwag/agent/sessions/ABwppHEUBtwbVHv-ECaw2yqSzZwdKjejoN3HrlpD8e0anrJytaT9jX8_zRMrW1-lJtC-W1TUFWKXLqLh/contexts/actions_capability_screen_output", "parameters": { "color": "blue", "color.original": "blue" } }, "actions_capability_audio_output": { "name": "projects/actions-rwag/agent/sessions/ABwppHEUBtwbVHv-ECaw2yqSzZwdKjejoN3HrlpD8e0anrJytaT9jX8_zRMrW1-lJtC-W1TUFWKXLqLh/contexts/actions_capability_audio_output", "parameters": { "color": "blue", "color.original": "blue" } }, "google_assistant_input_type_keyboard": { "name": "projects/actions-rwag/agent/sessions/ABwppHEUBtwbVHv-ECaw2yqSzZwdKjejoN3HrlpD8e0anrJytaT9jX8_zRMrW1-lJtC-W1TUFWKXLqLh/contexts/google_assistant_input_type_keyboard", "parameters": { "color": "blue", "color.original": "blue" } }, "actions_capability_web_browser": { "name": "projects/actions-rwag/agent/sessions/ABwppHEUBtwbVHv-ECaw2yqSzZwdKjejoN3HrlpD8e0anrJytaT9jX8_zRMrW1-lJtC-W1TUFWKXLqLh/contexts/actions_capability_web_browser", "parameters": { "color": "blue", "color.original": "blue" } }, "actions_capability_media_response_audio": { "name": "projects/actions-rwag/agent/sessions/ABwppHEUBtwbVHv-ECaw2yqSzZwdKjejoN3HrlpD8e0anrJytaT9jX8_zRMrW1-lJtC-W1TUFWKXLqLh/contexts/actions_capability_media_response_audio", "parameters": { "color": "blue", "color.original": "blue" } } }, "output": {} }, "incoming": { "parsed": [ "" ] }, "query": "blue", "data": {} }
4:19:11.346 PM dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment Headers { "host": "us-central1-actions-rwag.cloudfunctions.net", "user-agent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.4 (Java/1.8.0_181)", "transfer-encoding": "chunked", "accept": "text/plain, */*", "accept-charset": "big5, big5-hkscs, cesu-8, euc-jp, euc-kr, gb18030, gb2312, gbk, ibm-thai, ibm00858, ibm01140, ibm01141, ibm01142, ibm01143, ibm01144, ibm01145, ibm01146, ibm01147, ibm01148, ibm01149, ibm037, ibm1026, ibm1047, ibm273, ibm277, ibm278, ibm280, ibm284, ibm285, ibm290, ibm297, ibm420, ibm424, ibm437, ibm500, ibm775, ibm850, ibm852, ibm855, ibm857, ibm860, ibm861, ibm862, ibm863, ibm864, ibm865, ibm866, ibm868, ibm869, ibm870, ibm871, ibm918, iso-2022-cn, iso-2022-jp, iso-2022-jp-2, iso-2022-kr, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-13, iso-8859-15, iso-8859-2, iso-8859-3, iso-8859-4, iso-8859-5, iso-8859-6, iso-8859-7, iso-8859-8, iso-8859-9, jis_x0201, jis_x0212-1990, koi8-r, koi8-u, shift_jis, tis-620, us-ascii, utf-16, utf-16be, utf-16le, utf-32, utf-32be, utf-32le, utf-8, windows-1250, windows-1251, windows-1252, windows-1253, windows-1254, windows-1255, windows-1256, windows-1257, windows-1258, windows-31j, x-big5-hkscs-2001, x-big5-solaris, x-compound_text, x-euc-jp-linux, x-euc-tw, x-eucjp-open, x-ibm1006, x-ibm1025, x-ibm1046, x-ibm1097, x-ibm1098, x-ibm1112, x-ibm1122, x-ibm1123, x-ibm1124, x-ibm1166, x-ibm1364, x-ibm1381, x-ibm1383, x-ibm300, x-ibm33722, x-ibm737, x-ibm833, x-ibm834, x-ibm856, x-ibm874, x-ibm875, x-ibm921, x-ibm922, x-ibm930, x-ibm933, x-ibm935, x-ibm937, x-ibm939, x-ibm942, x-ibm942c, x-ibm943, x-ibm943c, x-ibm948, x-ibm949, x-ibm949c, x-ibm950, x-ibm964, x-ibm970, x-iscii91, x-iso-2022-cn-cns, x-iso-2022-cn-gb, x-iso-8859-11, x-jis0208, x-jisautodetect, x-johab, x-macarabic, x-maccentraleurope, x-maccroatian, x-maccyrillic, x-macdingbat, x-macgreek, x-machebrew, x-maciceland, x-macroman, x-macromania, x-macsymbol, x-macthai, x-macturkish, x-macukraine, x-ms932_0213, x-ms950-hkscs, x-ms950-hkscs-xp, x-mswin-936, x-pck, x-sjis_0213, x-utf-16le-bom, x-utf-32be-bom, x-utf-32le-bom, x-windows-50220, x-windows-50221, x-windows-874, x-windows-949, x-windows-950, x-windows-iso2022jp", "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8", "function-execution-id": "gjnwrdpyi1ax", "x-appengine-api-ticket": "e212b331d87bdb3c", "x-appengine-city": "?", "x-appengine-citylatlong": "0.000000,0.000000", "x-appengine-country": "US", "x-appengine-default-version-hostname": "l9ec7ba250478215b-tp.appspot.com", "x-appengine-https": "on", "x-appengine-region": "?", "x-appengine-request-log-id": "5bac13ef00ff00ffe3280c8cb3550001737e6c396563376261323530343738323135622d7470000139303866373866633530636138623435363966303164656633393333393136383a3233000100", "x-appengine-user-ip": "35.239.85.110", "x-cloud-trace-context": "0109e1b3b7dc8fbbefd2664dbcbd5d0a/2770932151653705781;o=1", "x-forwarded-for": "35.239.85.110, 35.239.85.110", "x-forwarded-proto": "https", "accept-encoding": "gzip" }
4:19:11.339 PM dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment Request { "responseId": "c7b55f8a-502d-431a-8056-258dec82268f", "queryResult": { "queryText": "blue", "parameters": { "color": "blue" }, "allRequiredParamsPresent": true, "fulfillmentMessages": [ { "text": { "text": [ "" ] } } ], "outputContexts": [ { "name": "projects/actions-rwag/agent/sessions/ABwppHEUBtwbVHv-ECaw2yqSzZwdKjejoN3HrlpD8e0anrJytaT9jX8_zRMrW1-lJtC-W1TUFWKXLqLh/contexts/actions_capability_screen_output", "parameters": { "color": "blue", "color.original": "blue" } }, { "name": "projects/actions-rwag/agent/sessions/ABwppHEUBtwbVHv-ECaw2yqSzZwdKjejoN3HrlpD8e0anrJytaT9jX8_zRMrW1-lJtC-W1TUFWKXLqLh/contexts/actions_capability_audio_output", "parameters": { "color": "blue", "color.original": "blue" } }, { "name": "projects/actions-rwag/agent/sessions/ABwppHEUBtwbVHv-ECaw2yqSzZwdKjejoN3HrlpD8e0anrJytaT9jX8_zRMrW1-lJtC-W1TUFWKXLqLh/contexts/google_assistant_input_type_keyboard", "parameters": { "color": "blue", "color.original": "blue" } }, { "name": "projects/actions-rwag/agent/sessions/ABwppHEUBtwbVHv-ECaw2yqSzZwdKjejoN3HrlpD8e0anrJytaT9jX8_zRMrW1-lJtC-W1TUFWKXLqLh/contexts/actions_capability_web_browser", "parameters": { "color": "blue", "color.original": "blue" } }, { "name": "projects/actions-rwag/agent/sessions/ABwppHEUBtwbVHv-ECaw2yqSzZwdKjejoN3HrlpD8e0anrJytaT9jX8_zRMrW1-lJtC-W1TUFWKXLqLh/contexts/actions_capability_media_response_audio", "parameters": { "color": "blue", "color.original": "blue" } } ], "intent": { "name": "projects/actions-rwag/agent/intents/8524ede6-72a2-467b-9b34-67a8f1d3a121", "displayName": "favorite color" }, "intentDetectionConfidence": 1, "languageCode": "en-us" }, "originalDetectIntentRequest": { "source": "google", "version": "2", "payload": { "isInSandbox": true, "surface": { "capabilities": [ { "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER" }, { "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO" }, { "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT" }, { "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT" } ] }, "requestType": "SIMULATOR", "inputs": [ { "rawInputs": [ { "query": "blue", "inputType": "KEYBOARD" } ], "arguments": [ { "rawText": "blue", "textValue": "blue", "name": "text" } ], "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT" } ], "user": { "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}", "lastSeen": "2018-09-26T23:19:06Z", "locale": "en-US", "userId": "ABwppHHp5yhn_VrB_SIGG93tCzMx9o0A_W9bIDlbCClkqcV85LrVbJ42vLQ7hWXfe3UOd7pASDIm6v_q" }, "conversation": { "conversationId": "ABwppHEUBtwbVHv-ECaw2yqSzZwdKjejoN3HrlpD8e0anrJytaT9jX8_zRMrW1-lJtC-W1TUFWKXLqLh", "type": "ACTIVE", "conversationToken": "[]" }, "availableSurfaces": [ { "capabilities": [ { "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER" }, { "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT" }, { "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT" } ] } ] } }, "session": "projects/actions-rwag/agent/sessions/ABwppHEUBtwbVHv-ECaw2yqSzZwdKjejoN3HrlpD8e0anrJytaT9jX8_zRMrW1-lJtC-W1TUFWKXLqLh" }
4:19:11.063 PM dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment Function execution started
```

Comment: Is the PHP never called? Or is it just called somewhat later than you expect? Are there any logs in Firebase Cloud Functions that show an error or anything unexpected?

Comment: The PHP is never called. The logs in Firebase Cloud Functions don't show anything unexpected - no errors or anything, and no mention whatsoever of the GET request. I'll add a snipped from the log to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've discovered why I was running into this problem, and why I couldn't explain it based on research into Actions on Google or Node.js. It looks like the page on my server that I was requesting returns a 301 "Permanently Moved" response. When I request the page through a web browser, it ignores(?) this response and serves the page anyway, but when I make the request in my AoG intent fulfillment, it silently recognizes the 301 and doesn't ever hit the PHP on the server. Anyway, it appears this is a problem with my server configuration and not my AoG code.

Hot tip to new AoG programmers: console.log() commands in the fulfillment will appear in the Firebase Cloud Functions log, which is what eventually allowed me to see the 301 code being returned. Thanks to anyone how tried to puzzle this out with me!